# How can I enhance this

Tags: javascript, svg

I want to add another connector to "A" Block to "C" block. How can I enhance the following snippets to achieve my requirement? Refer the image and jsfidle link

https://jsfiddle.net/dw03zj39/

[image]

```
var divA      = document.querySelector("#a");
var divB      = document.querySelector("#b");
var connector = document.querySelector("#connector");

var drawConnector = function() {
  var posnA = {
    x: divA.offsetLeft + divA.offsetWidth,
    y: divA.offsetTop  + divA.offsetHeight / 2
  };
  var posnB = {
    x: divB.offsetLeft,
    y: divB.offsetTop  + divA.offsetHeight / 2
  };
  var dStr =
      "M" +
      (posnA.x      ) + "," + (posnA.y) + " " +
      "C" +
      (posnA.x + 100) + "," + (posnA.y) + " " +
      (posnB.x - 100) + "," + (posnB.y) + " " +
      (posnB.x      ) + "," + (posnB.y);
  connector.setAttribute("d", dStr);
};

window.addEventListener("resize", drawConnector);

drawConnector();
```

Comment: Your question is incomplete. Please describe what you would like to achieve and post your code to check the issue.

Comment: Question updated with image and jsfidle link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the "from" and "to" elements parameters.

Something like the following should work:

```
var divA      = document.querySelector("#a");
var divB      = document.querySelector("#b");
var divC      = document.querySelector("#c");
var connector = document.querySelector("#connector");

var drawConnector = function(from, to) {
  var posnA = {
    x: from.offsetLeft + from.offsetWidth,
    y: from.offsetTop  + from.offsetHeight / 2
  };
  var posnB = {
    x: to.offsetLeft,
    y: to.offsetTop  + to.offsetHeight / 2
  };
  var dStr =
      "M" +
      (posnA.x      ) + "," + (posnA.y) + " " +
      "C" +
      (posnA.x + 100) + "," + (posnA.y) + " " +
      (posnB.x - 100) + "," + (posnB.y) + " " +
      (posnB.x      ) + "," + (posnB.y);
  connector.setAttribute("d", dStr);
};

function drawAllConnectors()
{
  drawConnector(divA, divB);
  drawConnector(divA, divC);
}

window.addEventListener("resize", drawAllConnectors);

drawAllConnectors();
```

Comment: You'll need an extra connector element in the SVG. https://jsfiddle.net/dw03zj39/2/